# Variável do javascript dentro da Tag do EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Como coloco uma variável do javascript dentro da Tag do EJS?

Por exemplo, desejo fazer um `for` pelo EJS e um `if` comparando:

```
<% for (var i = 0 ; i < objeto.lenght; i++ ) { %>
    <% if (objeto[i].index == variável_externa) { %>
        ..... 
    <% } %> 
<% } %>
```

---

'''
Meu código está abaixo: 
Eu quero colocar uma váriavel do javascript dentro de uma EJS 
'''

```
document.getElementById("indicadores1").addEventListener('change', (event) => {
// Aqui eu obtenho meu value 
let indicador_atual = event.target.value;
console.log(indicador_atual);
// Agora preciso colocar esse valor dentro de uma váriavel EJS

Por exemplo :<% x %>= indicador_atual
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `<%= variavel %>`, similar ao PHP.

```
<% for (var i = 0 ; i < objeto.lenght; i++ ) { %>
    <% if (objeto[i].index == variável_externa) { %>
        <%= objeto[i].nome %>
    <% } %> 
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `<%= variavel %>` ou `<%- variavel %>`.

A diferença entre os dois modos é que `<%- variavel %>` interpreta códigos HTML, enquanto `<%= variavel %>` não.

[Fonte](https://github.com/tj/ejs#features)